# Loading a custom library with JNA on Windows

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna

I have a .c file in which are defined methods with `JNIEXPORT` and i don't know how use these methods in a Java class importing them with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna)

I try to read [this guide](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) but I don't understand if it's possible to link a specific .c file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: @user43250937 Windows

Comment: Ok, the code is the same as below, just build the dll as you are used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, build and compile a shared library as you usually do   and load it with `Native.loadLibrary`.

**C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void exampleMethod(const char* value)
{
    printf("%s\n", value);
}
```

Compile it in the usual way (showing gcc on linux here):

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC test.c
gcc -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

**Java:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class TestJNA{
  public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public void exampleMethod(String val);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CLibrary mylib = (CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("test", CLibrary.class);
    mylib.exampleMethod("ImAString");
  }

}
```

Since you are having issues finding the library, this is usually fixed configuring the `java.library.path` adding a new location where .so/.dll will be searched:

```
java -Djava.library.path=c:\dlllocation TestJNA
```

Alternatively you can set it directly from your code before loading the library (works with JNI, should work with JNA too, but i didn't try it):

```
String libspath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
libspath = libspath + ";c:/dlllocation";
System.setProperty("java.library.path",libspath);

//Load your library here
```

Comment: I used this example to build a .dll file. But when I run the code `Unable to load library 'test.dll'`. The file is positioned in the same directory of the .c and .java file. Wat is the correct location of the .dll file created ?

Comment: Are you launching from console/terminal or using eclipse?

Comment: @ user43250937 I'm using NetBeans and I run the class with the `main` method.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, the dll should be placed in the project root, from console you can either put it in `c:\windows\system32`(ugly) or set the library path: `java -Djava.library.path=c:\dlllocation TestJNA`

Comment: Ok, updating the answer to make it work with every ide.

Comment: Done, before trying that approach i'd try just putting it in the netbeans project root.

Comment: Yes it's right. I solved some minutes ago using `System.setProperty`, the rest of code was correct, I dont'use the  `java -Djava.library.path=c:\dlllocation TestJNA` command but it works anyway. Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer of "uraimo" for jna it should use jna.library.path instead of java.library.path and that should solve the location issue.